# How do I draw on a mesh and animate keyframes for those strokes efficiently?

Tags: grease-pencil

I want to animate a cube with eyes that blink as the cube turns in mid-air.
[image: something like this]
The thing is, I find that the strokes separate from the cube's surface as the cube rotates.
Is there a better way to animate the blinking eyes than to keyframe the eyes' position relative to the cube?